# Driving emissives with mesh objests

Tags: shaders, lighting, drivers, emission

Is there a way to achieve something similar with Blender? Specifically, I want to drive the lights with a 3d mesh.
https://youtu.be/zRJ_HWQ7peE

Comment: Hello and welcome. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link and ask How do I do this?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gross way to do it. Unfortunately I couldn't use the *NLA* with the node actions which would have made it simpler, either I miss something or Blender doesn't manage node actions like other actions:

- Create 4 spheres within one single object, unwrap with *Project From View*, build the following node setup, basically a *ColorRamp* is used to manage a transition between a blue emission and transparency, I made the setup a bit more complex as I wanted a bit of *Layer Weight*. At frame 0 set the *Mapping Location* value in order to make the object completely transparent, keyframe the value:

[image]

- At frame X, change the *Location* value so that the sphere are now completely lit:

[image]

- select the object and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to link-duplicate, move the duplication, rotate it, duplicate it again to create a whole triangle. Also duplicate the material and change the *Mapping Location* values in order to delay the light:

[image]